# How to get proper item in listview?

Tags: android

I writing test application and I get a strange behavior of mainActivity.listItem, when I click on item yet another item can get visible,it can get dissapear by scrolling.I'm confused.Thanks!

MainActivity

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    stethoInit();

    mainActivity = DataBindingUtil.setContentView(this, R.layout.activity_main);

    if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN) {
        cursor = getContentResolver().query(MyProvider.CONTENT_URI, null, null, null, null, null);
    }

    String[] from = new String[]{MyProvider.ID, MyProvider.TEXT};
    int[] to = new int[]{R.id.t_id, R.id.t_text};

    scAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, R.layout.item, cursor, from, to, 0);

    mainActivity.listItem.setAdapter(scAdapter);
    scAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

    mainActivity.listItem.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            FrameLayout v = (FrameLayout)view.findViewById(R.id.updateLayout);
            Log.d("!!!",v.toString());

            v.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }
    });

    mainActivity.insert.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Fragment insertFragment = new Insert();
            FragmentTransaction ft = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
            ft.replace(R.id.container, insertFragment);
            ft.addToBackStack(null);
            ft.setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_FADE);
            ft.commit();
        }
    });
}
```

item.xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"  >

<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/updateLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:visibility="gone">

    <!-- TODO: Update blank fragment layout -->

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/updateTextField"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="@string/insertTextFieldHint"
        android:focusable="false"
        android:inputType="textPersonName" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/uodateRecButton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="125dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="65dp"
        android:focusable="false"
        android:text="@string/updateRecButton" />

</FrameLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/checkBox"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:focusable="false"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/t_id"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/t_text"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1" />

</LinearLayout>
```

**UPDATE**
I solved this problem by extending SimpleCursorAdapter ,maybe someone share with another solution?

```
private class MyAdapter extends SimpleCursorAdapter{
    private int layout;
    public MyAdapter(Context context, int layout, Cursor c, String[] from, int[] to, int flags) {
        super(context, layout, c, from, to, flags);
        this.layout = layout;
    }

    @Override
    public void bindView(View view, Context context, Cursor cursor) {
        String id = cursor.getString(colId);
        String title = cursor.getString(colText);

        TextView idView = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.t_id);
        idView.setText(id);
        TextView textView = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.t_text);
        textView.setText(title);

    }

    @Override
    public View newView(Context context, Cursor cursor, ViewGroup parent) {
        View view = getLayoutInflater().inflate(layout,parent,false);
        return view;
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemViewType(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public int getViewTypeCount() {
        return getCount();
    }
}
```

Comment: What's mainActivity.insert? can't see a view with that name in the xml

Comment: mainActivity.insert is a binding for  insert button,but it work's good.I have problem with mainActivity.listItem.setOnItemClickListener